# How to count the time of creation and termination of n threads and fork()'s?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, pthreads, fork

Where `n` is a value read at the beginning.

First of all, when creating the thread and the fork(), what should it do? Simply `return NULL` or output something?

I've thought of doing something like this, for measuring the threads, after reading `n`:

```
pthread_t threads[n];
begin = clock();
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    //cout << " main() created thread number: " << i << endl;
    ret = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, Threads, (void *)i);
}
end = clock();
time = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

It's accurate? A good way to calculate it? And for the fork()'s I thought of something like this:

```
begin = clock();

if (fork() == 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        j += i;
    }
    exit(0);
}

end = clock();
time = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

Comment: What is it that you actually want to measure?  In the first snippet, for example, all you're timing is how long it takes to create `n` threads.

Comment: Oh, I just forgot to say it, I want to measure the creation and their termination. I'll edit it right away!

Comment: Is it really necessary to measure the time from inside the program. Invoking the program with `/usr/bin/time -v program args` will give you more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided getting two other codes, where the `fork()` and the thread would do:

```
void do_nothing() {
   int i;
   i = 0;
 }
```

The best way I've found to calculate the time, was executing the invoking the time. For `n = 50000` I've obtained:

```
$ time ./forks

real    0m25.064s
user    0m3.389s
sys     0m12.731s

$ time ./pthreads

real    0m2.164s
user    0m0.262s
sys     0m1.616s
```

So, I created processes using `fork()` and created (and destroyed) threads that simply created a variable and gave the value `0` to them.